# how to show data on recycler view from edittext

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to show data on `RecyclerView` that i get from user via `EditText`. How can i do this?

The code:

```
public class MyRecyler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyler.MyHolder> {
    Context context;
    String names;

    public MyRecyler(Context context, String names) {
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.names, parent, false);
        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.name.setText(this.names.indexOf(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.names.length();
    }

    public class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;

        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MyRecyler obj = new MyRecyler(this,editText.getText().toString());
                recyclerView.setAdapter(obj);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First use a arraylist to store your string.

```
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>()
names.add("name1")
names.add("name2")
names.add("name3")

YourAdapter adapter = new Adapter(this, names)
rView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

Pass this arraylist in your recyclerview

Suppose you have a itemlist to show data on recyclerview. First get the size of the itemlist and insert your value using these below function.

```
public int getItemCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}
```

Insert the item as the last item of the recyclerview

```
 public void add(MODEL object) {
    itemList.add(object);
    notifyItemInserted(getItemCount() - 1);
}
```

Insert the item in your given position.

```
public void add(int position, MODEL object) {
    itemList.add(position, object);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
```

notifyiteminserted() will notify the recycler view that there is a new data to show.

As an example

```
String str = editext.getText().toString()
//ur_model = the model you used in your recycler view
// setName(str) is a setter function which will set the str
ur_model.setName(str)
// Passing your model and updating the recyclerview
adapter.add(ur_model)
```